# php - Mysql where name is in array

Tags: php, mysql

```
   $CustomerName= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.,& ]/','',$row["Customer_Name"]);
   array_push($CustomerName2,$CustomerName);
   $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM Customer where Customer_Name IN ($CustomerName2)";
   $stmt = mysql_query($conn,$sqlquery);
   echo(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))    
   {    
       $sqlCustomerIdMaps[$row[0]]= $row[0];
   }
```

I am not well with php, in above php code querying data from sql .My output is from array `$CustomerName2` like:

```
Array ( [0] => Acme Janitor & Chemical Supply [1] => Adam Zampa [2] => AMAZON.COM PHOENIX PHX6 [3] => Aston Agar [4] => Austin Consulting Group [5] => Brad Hodge [6] => Cedrick Johnson [7] => Crowen [8] => David Miller [9] => David Warner [10] => DKR [11] => DKR [12] => DKR [13] => Jaworskyj Gabrielle [14] => Johan2 [15] => Jone [16] => Keith Olson [17] => Mallika [18] => Manoj Reddy [19] => Michael Bevan [20] => Philip Andry [21] => Shane1 Warne1 [22] => Spad Consulting Group [23] => Usman Khawaja [24] => Zohar )
```

In sql query i am not getting any errors but query is not working?

I need to query with Customer_Name and add result to map to update data in sql server.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$CustomerName2` is an array, and you are trying to use it as a string when you make your query. Change that code to:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * 
    FROM Customer
    WHERE Customer_Name IN ('" . implode("','", $CustomerName2) . "')";
```

**Update**

You are using the wrong database library to fetch your data. Based on the fact that you are connecting to a MySQL database using the `mysqli` library, you should rewrite the last part of your code to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery);
echo mysqli_errno($conn);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) {
    $sqlCustomerIdMaps[$row[0]]= $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

Comment: When i replace with your suggetion, i am getting "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';'" this error.

Comment: Sorry I had a couple of typos. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks you for your patience to answer me.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) ) getting this error...

Comment: How is `$conn` being assigned?

Comment: I am assigned it from another php file: require_once ('MySQLcredentials.php');

Comment: Could you post the line of code which assigns it please.

Comment: <?php
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password ";
$dbname = "dbname ";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("server name", "user name", "password", "dbname ");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error;
}
    echo " connected successfully";
?>

Comment: Ok, so your problem is you're making a connection with `mysqli`. So you either need to use `mysqli` functions to access the database or use `sqlsrv_connect` to connect to the database. Which is appropriate will depend on whether you have  a `MySQL` or `SQLServer` database

Comment: My database is MySQLDB

Comment: Thanks Nick. It is working with $stmt = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlquery);

Comment: Hi @NarendraReddy just edited the answer to show mysqli code. If it is working, I'd appreciate you marking the answer accepted.